# Data is not inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys i am using this code, to insert data from FORM to my database, but actualy its not working, my code looks like:

```
<?php

class WebsiteUsers {
public $username = null;
public $email = null;
public $phone = null;
public $message = null;

public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
if( isset( $data['email'] ) ) $this->email = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['email'] ) );
if( isset( $data['phone'] ) ) $this->phone = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['phone'] ) );
if( isset( $data['message'] ) ) $this->message = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['message'] ) );
}

public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
//store the parameters
$this->__construct( $params );
}

public function userLogin() {
$success = false;
try{
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "phone", $this->phone, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "message", $this->message, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();

$valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if( $valid ) {
$success = true;
}

$con = null;
return $success;
}catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
return $success;
}
}

public function message() {
$correct = false;
try {
$con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "INSERT INTO user(name, email, phone, message) VALUES(:name, :email, :phone, :message)";

$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "email", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "phone", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "message", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();
return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
}catch( PDOException $e ) {
return $e->getMessage();
}
}

}

?>
```

and my index.php looks like:

```
<?php if( !(isset( $_POST['send'] ) ) ) { ?>

HTML FORM

<?php 
} else {
    $WebsiteUsers = new WebsiteUsers();
    $WebsiteUsers->storeFormValues( $_POST );
    if( $WebsiteUsers->message() ) {
        echo "Sprava bola odoslana";    
    } else {
        echo "Sprava nebola odoslana";    
    }
}

?>
```

When i submit th form it says Sprava bola odoslana but it dont enter anything to DB also do not display any error, can somebody help me to fix it?

Comment: Look at the `__construct` in your class; you're assigning four different values to `$this->username`. When you do the add, you're not using `$this->username` at all - you're using `$this->name`. You need to check the names of the variables are correct

Comment: `if( isset( $array['name'] ) ) $this->name = stripslashes( $array['name'] );
         if( isset( $array['message'] ) ) $this->message = stripslashes( $array['message'] );
         if( isset( $array['phone'] ) ) $this->phone = stripslashes( $array['phone'] );
         if( isset( $array['email'] ) ) $this->email = stripslashes( $array['email'] );`

Sorry you were right and i fix it, but its still sending it to DB twice :(

Comment: Oh guys i just noticed one thing, this code is actualy not working, it was adding twicee because of other class which is included, when i comment it (stop using it) it dont add anything to database dispite the fact it send message  that "Sprava bola odoslana" which should be send when its done correctly

Comment: You need to fix all the `name` versus `username` differences in the code, and you need to assign to the proper properties. It's a total mess.

Comment: @RichardSabol - your method either returns `Sprava odoslana` or `$exce->getMessage()`. However - when you call it, you've got it wrapped in `if( $Users->message() )`. That will evaluate to true no matter which option your method returns - it's returning a string either way. You probably want to return either true or false instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a param `:name` in your INSERT sql, but your first `$stmt->bindValue()` is binding value to `username`.

other than that, you shouldnt call constructor in another method. Your code may get run twice.